# Error: Could not find or load main class bankAccount.BankAccount

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java and trying to compile and run a simple program.  It compiles successfully. But throws error when I try to run. Can anyone point out the mistake I did. The error is below.

```
"Error: Could not find or load main class bankAccount.BankAccount"
```

Below is the code.

```
package bankAccount;

class AccountDetails{
    private String fName;
    private String mName;
    private String lName;
    private String mailId;
    private String dob;
    private char gender;
    private String mStatus;
    private int custID;
    private int accountNo;
    private int minBalance;
    private static int counter=1000;
    private static int counter1=10000;
    private String typeOfAccount;
    public AccountDetails(String fName, String mName, String lName, String mailId, String dob, char gender, String mStatus)
    {
        this.fName=fName;
        this.mName=mName;
        this.lName=lName;
        this.mailId=mailId;
        this.dob=dob;
        this.gender=gender;
        this.mStatus=mStatus;
        custID=++counter;
        accountNo=++counter1;
        if (typeOfAccount.equalsIgnoreCase("salary")){
            minBalance=0;
        }
        else if (typeOfAccount.equalsIgnoreCase("nonsalary")){
        minBalance=1000;
        }
    }
    public void displayAcc(){
        System.out.println("fname: "+fName);
        System.out.println("mname: "+mName);
        System.out.println("lname: "+lName);
        System.out.println("mailId: "+mailId);
        System.out.println("Date of Birth: "+dob);
        System.out.println("gender: "+gender);
        System.out.println("Marital Status: "+mStatus);
        System.out.println("Account No: "+accountNo);
        System.out.println("Customer ID: "+custID);
        System.out.println("Type of Account: "+typeOfAccount);
        System.out.println("Min. Balance: "+minBalance);
        }

}

public class BankAccount {
public static void main(){
    AccountDetails acObj1 = new AccountDetails("Paul","J","AnderSon","Paul@gmail.com","3rd Jan, 1985",'M',"Single");
    acObj1.displayAcc();
}
}
```

Comment: Signature of main should be `public static void main (String[] args)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change singnature of main method from

```
public static void main(){
```

to

```
public static void main(String[] args){
```

when running the class `BankAccount`(or any other class) jvm searches for its main method having String array as arguments to be used as an entry point so in your case jvm is not able to find it as you dont have correct arguments

For the second part

you have only declared `typeOfAccount` but not intialiazed as I can see and you are doing `typeOfAccount.equalsIgnoreCase()` means it would be something like `null.equalsIgnoreCase()`(null default value of string) giving you a null pointer exception.

Comment: Now I am getting the same error if I run it from command prompt. If I run it from eclipse I am getting below error.

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
         at bankAccount.AccountDetails.<init>(BankAccount.java:28)
         at bankAccount.BankAccount.main(BankAccount.java:53)

Comment: you have to `javac BankAccount.java` first then `java BankAccount `

Comment: @user3123752 that error is unrelated to your current question. It is because the `typeOfAccount` variable is `null`. You need to initialize the variable before using it.

Comment: @user3123752 if your getting a null pointer exception the issue isn't with the class path. Your code is compiling and executing but there's an error while executing the code. Simple fix would be to just initialize your `typeOfAccount` variable. Say `typeOfAccount = "salary"`

Comment: @ug_ thanks.. that was the problem. However if I run it from command prompt, same error but from eclipse it works.

Comment: @user3123752 I have updated my answer and while running from cmd did you do `javac BankAccount.java` first

Comment: @singhakash yes I did and it compiles fine. But java BankAccount.java fails with error that class not found. Is it by any chance related to CLASSPATH?

Comment: yes its a classpath issue did you set the environment variable

Comment: @singhakash yes I did set it. But I am always confused on how exactly it should be.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set typeOfAccount so when you refer to it in your constructor here;

```
if (typeOfAccount.equalsIgnoreCase("salary"))
```

and here;

```
else if (typeOfAccount.equalsIgnoreCase("nonsalary"))
```

typeOfAccount will equal neither, therefore minBalance won't be set, hence you will get a NullPointerException here;

```
System.out.println("Type of Account: "+typeOfAccount);
```

and here;

```
System.out.println("Min. Balance: "+minBalance);
```

Because these values haven't been set.